# iOS synchronize device operation with clock

Tags: objective-c, ios, synchronization, clock, gamekit

I'm trying to synchronize two iOS devices, in the way that they can start an operation at the same time. The real application of these will be that both devices take a photo in the same time or start recording video at the same time.
I'm actually using gamekit to make the device communicate through bluetooth, but I'm not sure how much can I rely on the device's clock.
And one other thing, anyone knows about the maximum delay of bluetooth transmission?
Anyone has a protocol or a way to synchronize the two device?